# Trying to Bluetooth connect with createBond , but the connection with the remote device generates ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED

Tags: bluetooth

I'm doing a Bluetooth scanner in Android. The app scans the available remote devices, filter them by name and mac, and connect with the first one that fits. Then, the app sends to it a song by A2DP streaming

What the app is doing is create a bond with the method:

myDeviceBT.createBond()

Then , a ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED is generated with myBluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED detected.

This is working fine in a Samsung Galaxy J3 (Android 9)

However, when I try to run the app in a Asus X008D (Android 7) and Motorola Moto E (Android 5.1) the problem is that, after createBond(), the result is ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED

What is the reason for that? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

The problem is that there is two different concepts which are "bond" and "connect".

Bond is to stablish the communicatrion between both devices, and connect is to stablish a common profile between them

And the problem was origined because the createBond() method makes different things in different platforms, and it is not related to the API version, but it is related to the android implementation in different hardwares

In a Samsung Galaxy J3 (Android 9) and Lenovo A2016 (Android 6) createBond() executes both operations for connecting: bond and A2DP connect

In a Asus X008D (Android 7) and Motorola XT1021 (Android 5.1) createBon() just makes the bond, and then a A2DP connection is necessary aftes bonded has been successful!

So, the correct sequence must be:

1.- createBond()
2.- wait for BONDED event
3.- connect A2DP proxy
4.- wait for A2DP CONNECTED event

This works in all those platforms

Problem fixed.